# Jest Testing React Form Submit

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting an error when trying to test a React form submission.  The error reads `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` . I have found other users with a similar problem but mine is unique as I use I use `event.target.elements` rather than `event.target.value`.

Here is the function I am testing:

```
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { createPassword, confirmPassword } = event.target.elements;
    if (createPassword.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
      setPassValidationError("*Passwords must match!");
    } else if (createPassword.value.length < 8) {
      setPassValidationError("*Passwords must be at least 8 characters long!");
    } else if (createPassword.value.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
      setPassValidationError(
        "*Passwords must contain at least one uppercase letter!"
      );
    } else if (createPassword.value.search(/[!@#$%^&*]/) < 0) {
      setPassValidationError(
        "*Passwords must contain at least one special character!"
      );
    } else {
      props.updatePassword({
        uid: props.uid,
        token: props.token,
        new_password: createPassword.value
      });
      event.target.reset();
    }
  };
```

Here are the input fields that are used on the form:

```
<input id="create-password" type={passType} required />
<input id="confirm-password" type={passType} required />
```

Now when I run my tests I expect `createPassword.value` and `confirmPassword.value` to take the values of their respective input field's mocked data.  Here is my test:

```
it("passwords must be 8 char long", () => {
  const onMock = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = mount(<NoAuthPasswordChange handleSubmit={onMock} />);
  const passInput = wrapper.find("#create-password");
  const confirmPass = wrapper.find("#confirm-password");
  passInput.simulate("change", { target: { value: "QQQQQQ" } });
  confirmPass.simulate("change", { target: { value: "QQQQQQ" } });
  const form = wrapper.find("#no-auth-password-change-form");
  form.simulate("submit", { preventDefault: () => {} });
  expect(wrapper.find("#password-validation-error").text()).toContain(
    "*Passwords must be at least 8 characters long!"
  );
});
```

What do I to do so that `createPassword.value` exists?

Comment: Does this code snippet work and it's just the test breaking? On what part does this error occur? `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: @adamz4008 yes the code works.  The test response is telling me that `value` is not defined for `createPassword.value` . I am thinking this has something to do with `simulate` not having an `event` tied to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
form.simulate('submit', {
  preventDefault: () => {},
  target: {
    elements: {
      createPassword: { value: 'blah' },
      confirmPassword: { value: 'some value' }
    }
 });
```

Comment: what would I use for the `name` field here?

Comment: Oops I don't think it's necessary to put name there. Too used to using `target.name/value` :-D. Edited.

Comment: This seems to work.  It isn't quite how I want the test to function as I would ideally assign each input field a respective value and then submit the form, but I believe this will work fine!

Comment: It's a good idea to do that you'd need to change `handleSubmit()` because it looks for elements property on submit. Also when dealing with forms in React it's nice to use a "controlled form" where your input values are synchronized with some component state, simplifies things a bit.